# Non-empty fields are empty in word

Tags: c#, xml, sharepoint, ms-word, spfield

I have created a multicolumn custom field and deployed it in SharePoint. To be able to use the field values from my custom field I also deployed an event receiver to copy the three values from my custom field to three separate regular text fields. If the three text fields do not exist I create them with XML in code. I also make sure the fields have the right visibility settings even if the field exist.

Creating the field in xml:

```
string fieldXml = string.Format("<Field ID=\"{0}\" " +
                                    "Type=\"{1}\" " +
                                    "Name=\"{2}\" " +
                                    "StaticName=\"{2}\" " +
                                    "DisplayName=\"{2}\" " +
                                    "Required=\"{3}\" " +
                                    "ShowInEditForm=\"TRUE\" " +
                                    "ShowInNewForm=\"TRUE\" " +
                                    "ShowInDisplayForm=\"TRUE\" " +
                                    "ShowInListSettings=\"TRUE\" " +
                                    "ShowInViewForms=\"TRUE\" " +
                                    "ShowInVersionHistory=\"TRUE\" " +
                                    "ShowInFileDlg=\"TRUE\"" +
                                    "></Field>",
                                    Guid.NewGuid(),
                                    fieldType,
                                    fieldName,
                                    required);

list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(fieldXml, true, SPAddFieldOptions.Default);
```

Make sure visibility settings OK when the field already exist:

```
field.ShowInEditForm = true;
field.ShowInNewForm = true;
field.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
field.ShowInListSettings = true;
field.ShowInViewForms = true;
field.ShowInVersionHistory = true;
field.Update();
list.Update();
```

I found no way of setting the ShowInFileDlg property programmatically once the field was created.

The thing is that this code works great up until I open a document in MS Word and the three text fields all have text assigned in the list but in Word they are empty!

Have anybody seen this before, what am I doing wrong!?

Comment: Solved it by using the docx extention instead of the old doc!

Comment: If someone has the time though. What is best practice regarding adding fields programmatically to list items. Should one add them to the content type, list or list item?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to open a field in DIP (document information panel at the top in word documents) you need to add the SourceId property to the field:

`SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3"`

For more information see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms196289.aspx) (msdn).